# sencha touch getView()?

Tags: sencha-touch

How can I call `getView(`view_name)` in Sencha touch? I usually do this on extjs but I can't in sencha touch. I could not understand the application concept.

```
run_edit: function(data) {
    $this = this;
    this.mode = "update";
    this.data = data;
    this.win = this.getView('Group_prop').create();

    var form = this.win.down('form');
    var util = this.getController('controller_Helper');

    form.getForm().loadRecord(data);
    util.form_lock({
        form:form,
        items:['GROUP_KODE']
    });
    util.form_require({
        form:form,
        items:['GROUP_KODE','GROUP_NAMA']
    });

    this.win.show();
},
```

Comment: Maybe you want to use `Ext.getCmp('the_component_id')`. Check the Sencha docs:http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-1/#!/api/Ext-method-getCmp

Comment: but the object have made yet. ?

Comment: Is this method part of your controller? And are you saying that you want to get the view via the controller?

Comment: yes, u're right. this is a part of my controller, n i want to get instance of my view (controller view).<br/>Usualy i use 'this.myview = this.getView("myview_name").create(); '.<br/>But i couldnot do this on sencha thouch

Comment: I wrote up and answer. I hope it is helpful. I assumed a few things since I did not have much to work with. Forgive me :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so it seems like you are trying to get the view: `Group_prop`. Make sure this view has an `id` or preferably an `itemId` set  in its config. e.g

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.GroupProb', {
    extend: 'Ext.Panel',
    alias: 'widget.group_prob',
    config: {
        ...
        itemId: 'groupProb',
        ...
    },
    ....
});
```

Now in your controller you need to create a reference for this view to access it properly. So your controller would look something like this:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.controller.MyController', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',
    config: {
        refs : {
            groupProb : {
                autoCreate: true,
                selector: '#groupProb',
                xtype: 'group_prob'
            }
        },
        control: {
            ...
        },
        ...
    },
    run_edit: function(data) {
        $this = this;
        this.mode = "update";
        this.data = data;
        this.win = this.getView('Group_prop').create();

        var form = this.win.down('form');
        var util = this.getController('controller_Helper');

        form.getForm().loadRecord(data);
        util.form_lock({
            form:form,
            items:['GROUP_KODE']
        });

        this.win.show();
    },
   ...
});
```

Now from your `run_edit` function, its seems like you are working with `windows` from the `this.win` variable (correct me if I'm wrong). Well in Sencha Touch, you work with `Panels`. Also at the end of this function you call the `show` function on `this.win`, which suggests that you want to execute `run_edit` when the `this.win` is shown. That being said, you may want to your `run_edit` function to look something like this:

```
run_edit: function() {
    var me = this,
        mode = 'update',
        data = data,
        groupProbPanel = me.getGroupProb();

    // This assumes that your form component has an itemId.
    // You need one inorder use the down method. 
    var form = groupProbPanel.down('#form_itemId');

    // You may want to double check this. I don't think that is how you 
    // you get the controller.
    var util = this.getController('controller_Helper');

    form.getForm().loadRecord(data);
    util.form_lock({
        form:form,
        items:['GROUP_KODE']
    });
}
```

Since we want this to happen when `groupProbPanel` is shown we need to set a [show event listener](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-1/#!/api/Ext.Panel-event-show) in our `control` config. So your controller's `config` should look like this:

```
...,
config: {
    refs : {
        groupProb : {
            autoCreate: true,
            selector: '#groupProb',
            xtype: 'group_prob'
        }
    },
    control: {
        groupProb : {
            show: 'run_edit'
        },
        ...
    },
    ...
},
...
```

Comment: wow, you rock.
thank you so much, i got this.
i have try this. N about the this.win, sorry i am a newbie in sencha touch:).
thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

I see you are trying to create a view and set it to window, in sencha touch you can do it like this:

```
Ext.Viewport.add(Ext.create('MyApp.view.ViewName'));
```

instead of Viewport you can take any other container and set newly created view to it

```
Ext.getCmp('myContainerId').add(Ext.create('MyApp.view.ViewName'));
```

to fetch this view later, you have to specify `id` config in view and then get it like this:

```
var view = Ext.getCmp('ViewId');
```

Answer (score 0):

Two ways is there to call the Views

1.

```
        Ext.Viewport.setActiveItem({xtype:'TwowayMakePayment'});  // view xtype
```

2.

```
        var getti=Ext.create('VUCFyn.view.AfterLogin'); //create object 4 d view
    Ext.Viewport.add(getti);       // next add the object
    Ext.Viewport.setActiveItem(getti);     // final Active that obj
```

Comment: i have try this one, but i want call the view (view that included in my controller) from the controller. what should i do?